# Unused property dropped?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, lodash

First things fist, my class:

```
export class FooBar {
 ...
 isFavorite: boolean = false;

 constructor() {
   this.isFavorite = false;
  }
}
```

Using Lodash I sort a list of `FooBar`, so my favorites would be on top of the list:

```
this.fooBars = _.orderBy(this.fooBars, ['isFavorite', 'name'], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

When I favorite an item and look at my console.log it states this:

[image: isFavorite is not shown when false]

Note that #3 does not have the isFavorite property...

Whenever I never set `isFavorite` it's not shown. This makes Lodash sort in a wrongly matter.
Is there a way to always show this property, even when it's unused/unset/false?

I tried:
 - Setting the property to false in the class
 - Setting the property to false in the constructor of the class
 - Looping over `this.foobars` in my component, setting them all to false
 - Adding an interface to `FooBar`

Comment: Defaulting the isFavorite property to false in the class declaration should works

Comment: You've correctly identified the issue: in JavaScript the default value is `undefined`. If you can show us the code of how those objects are constructed, we might be able to help you set the default value properly

Comment: @Vlad274 Valid question... the data comes from a .NET MVC API, but that .NET class does not have the property isFavorite. 
Could it be because of the serialization from .NET object to json the property gets removed since it doesn't exists on the API side?

Comment: Based on the .NET class not having the property, it's not so much that it "gets removed" but rather that it doesn't exist to begin with. This is the behavior I'd expect if you're doing some Angular binding to set it to true (such as with a checkbox).
If you absolutely 100% need the property to exist, you can add it to the objects in your service using the `.map` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the typeScript way to default a class propriety

```
export default class FooBar {
  constructor(private isFavorite: boolean = false) {
     ...
  }
}
```

or simply

```
export class FooBar {
  constructor() {
     this.isFavorite = false;
  }
}
```

Or you could use a function in the `_.orderBy` iteratee to sort your list accordingly:

```js
var foobars = [{isFavorite:false, name:"aaa"}, {isFavorite:true, name:"bbb"}, {isFavorite:false, name:"ccc"}, {name:"ddd"}]


foobars = _.orderBy(foobars, [function(foobar) {
    return foobar.isFavorite == true;
}, "name"], ["desc", "asc"]);

console.log(foobars)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```